# o.a.s.h.d.AuthenticatedURLDataSource Exception thrown while getting data java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, solr, odata

I am getting below error, while indexing the document in SOLR via OData. I am not getting always this error, frequently i am getting this error. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

For more information please find the image with error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPLyK.jpg).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: In local it is working fine, production only getting error. I don't have code access, I am form support team. I felt like some server setting or size but don't know what exactly. Also tried to update the time out duration.